# String to float conversion in Swift Beta 5

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The following code doesn't work anymore in Beta 5.

```
let device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
if (device.systemVersion.bridgeToObjectiveC().floatValue < 8.0) {
    [skipped]
}
```

Also, it's not possible to downcast a string to float.

```
let device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
let version: Float = device.systemVersion as Float
```

The snippet above returns the `'String' is not convertible to 'Float'` error.

Any ideas how should we test the OS version now? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`floatValue` is a method of `NSString`.
`Since bridgeToObjectiveC()` is no longer available with Xcode 6 Beta 5, you can use the `as` operator to cast your Swift `String` to `NSString`:

```
(device.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue
```

Comment: Just out of interest, do you know why we no longer have bridgeToObjC?

Comment: No idea but probably because in most cases one can achieve the same using the built-in type casting keyword. So bridgeToObjectiveC() would introduce redundancy and worse legibility.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this approach for now

```
("1.3" as NSString).floatValue
```